# Como colocar um link dentro de uma String?

Tags: string, link

Como coloco um link dentro de uma string?

```
var results = [
    {

        text: "Quero colocar um link aqui exemplo <a href="#"> Link </a>"; 
  },
```

Comment: É só escapar as aspas `"<a href=\"#\">"`. Aliás, quando você postar uma pergunta, use a tag da linguagem.

Answer (score 2):

### Respondendo a pergunta:

**Forma 1** - usando aspas simples:

```
text: "Quero colocar um link aqui exemplo <a href='#'> Link </a>";
```

**Forma 2** - usando escape:

```
text: "Quero colocar um link aqui exemplo <a href=\"#\"> Link </a>";
```

**Forma 3** - inserindo uma variável com a URL:

```
meulink = "#";
...
text: "Quero colocar um link aqui exemplo <a href=" + meulink + "> Link </a>";
```

**Forma 4** - Escapando o texto todo:

```
text: `Quero colocar um link aqui exemplo <a href="#"> Link </a>`;
```

### Informações extras

Baseando-me nos seus comentários, você provavelmente está se confundindo ao criar essa array e objeto, bem como tendo dificuldades em acessar por conta do primeiro erro. Veja:

```
var novo_array = [ 0, 1, 234 ];
var novo_objeto = { idade: 23, nome: "José da Silva", funcao: "Desenvolvedor" };
var objeto_em_array = [ 
    { 
        texto: "Objeto dentro do índice 0 do array", 
        texto2: "este também" 
    } 
];
```

Basicamente **você está criando objetos dentro de um array**. Como seu array tem índice 0, **você acessa os itens do objeto assim** - segundo o exemplo acima:

```
 objeto_em_array[0].texto
```

Não sei por que aninhou os dois ou se é necessário. Se não for, pode usar só o objeto.

Vou fornecer um exemplo funcional do que tentou fazer. **Atente-se apenas ao resultado executável e ao JavaScript**. O resto é desnecessário para o entendimento e pode ser ignorado pois serve apenas para ver a execução (visual). Veja

```js
var resultados = [ 
  { 
    texto: "Clique aqui para abrir o poderoso <a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Google</a>!",
    texto2: "Another object"
  }, 
  "Outro item do array",
  "Mais um item do array"
];

var popular = function(id){

  alvo = document.getElementById(id);

  alvo.innerHTML = resultados[0].texto;

};
```

```css
body { font-size: 12px; }

#nav { width: 22em; text-align: center; }

#formulario { float: left; width: 5em; margin: 0 2em 0 0; }

#saida { float: left; width: 15em; }

#cabecalho { background-color: #ffffaa; color: 333; padding: 0.5em; }

#destino { padding: 0.5em; }

.limpar { clear: both; }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div id="formulario">
    <form> 
      <input type="button" value="CLIQUE" onclick="javascript: popular('destino');" /> 
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="saida" >
    <div id="cabecalho">SAÍDA</div>
    <div id="destino"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="limpar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agradeço sua ajuda, porém nenhum desses métodos funcionou..

Você acha por eu estar usando uma Array, muda algo?

Comment: @OgaitEuqireh o fato de usar arrays, não. Mas você está usando array e objetos. O exemplo fornecido por você, especificamente `text`, é um objeto dentro da array `results` no índice `0`. O acesso se daria por `results[0].text` Fiz modificações; dê uma lida.

Answer (score 1):

É só utilizar aspas diferentes com as quais você abriu a string.

```js
  
  (function(){
  var results = [
    {

        text: 'Quero colocar um link aqui exemplo <a href="#"> Link </a>'
  }]
   document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML = results[0].text
  })()
```

```html
<p id="teste"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Existem três formas de você fazer isso, colocando uma " \ " (barra) no caractere desejado, iniciar a string com single quotes ou double quotes ou utilizando template literals (template strings).

A primeira forma é você iniciar com single quote e utilizar o double quote quando necessário:

```
var texto = 'Quero colocar um link aqui exemplo <a href="#"> Link </a>';
```

A segunda forma é você colocar a " \ " (barra invertida), ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
var texto = "Quero colocar um link aqui exemplo <a href=\"#\"> Link </a>";
```

A terceira forma é usar template literals, iniciando e finalizando a string com sinal de " ` " (Acento Grave)

```
var texto = `Quero colocar um link aqui exemplo <a href="#"> Link </a>`;
```

Note que esta última abordagem você precisará ficar atento quanto a compatibilidade dos navegadores. Um bom site de consulta é este [link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals)

Para mais informações sobre template literals, veja esta [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

Comment: Muito obrigado, mas não funcionou, eu estou usando uma array, sera que influencia em algo? obrigado

Comment: Não influencia, seria a mesma coisa. Como você está atribuindo o valor ao array? Dá alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Não da erro, simplesmente fica sem o link tipo:

texto texto <a href=""> link </a> 

estou atribuindo ele assim:
$(".js-renderResults").on("click", function () {
    var result = getResults();
});
  $(".js-resultsText").text(result.text);

Comment: Neste caso, acho que tem a ver com a atribuição do array pela posição. Dá uma lida na resposta do José que ele está explicando de forma mais completa como fazer isso.